# UITableView textLabel alignment

Tags: uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have a table view that looks like this:

[image]

I want the text that reads "laundry" to be aligned with the center of the cell. How would I do this?
The cell type is "Right Detail"

Comment: My first advice would be to create a custom UITabelViewCell class and add 3 labels to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the text that reads "laundry" to be aligned with the center of the cell. How would I do this? The cell type is "Right Detail"

The fact that the cell type is "Right Detail" is the problem. You don't get to say where the built-in text labels on the built-in cell types are placed; they are built in! If you don't like where they are, don't use the cell type "Right Detail". Use a custom cell type. Now you can put its labels wherever you like.

To be honest, you *can* move a built-in cell type's elements around, but only by subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding `layoutSubviews`, as in this example from my book:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let cvb = self.contentView.bounds
    let imf = self.imageView!.frame
    self.imageView!.frame.origin.x = cvb.size.width - imf.size.width - 15
    self.textLabel!.frame.origin.x = 15
}
```

But I can't recommend that sort of thing; you're just looking for trouble. Make a custom cell. It's standard procedure and is so much easier. The built-in cell types are just a "serving suggestion"; as soon as they don't fit your needs as is, you should abandon them.

Comment: And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_designing_a_cell_in_a_nib